# Instead of "all" or "all of," use "the entire" when you mean a total or the whole of a singular item

Tags: word-usage

Microsoft Word says that I SHOULD NOT use "all" or "all of" when I mean a total or the whole of a singular item and SHOULD use "the entire" instead. I typed "I am sick of all the lie" and Microsoft Word gave me a green squiggly line starting from "all" to "the." I'd like to know if this *were?* true, or my Microsoft Word is just not updated.

Comment: *I am sick of all the **lies**.* (This is a question for ELL.)

Comment: Some 'grammar-correcting' devices are better ignored.

Comment: What's ELL? Google says it's english-language learner. Then why "all of me" doesn't get that green line. "Me" is singular, right?

Comment: And some 'grammar-correcting' devices are better not ignored.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not in this case. The given suggestion is correct, but just not as useful to the OP as it does not question whether the object should be plural in the first place.

Comment: @Dog Lover If 'in this case' means the statement 'Microsoft Word says that I SHOULD NOT use "all" or "all of" when I mean a total or the whole of a singular item and SHOULD use "the entire" instead', it is far from being correct. 'He was awake all night' and 'He was awake the entire night' are interchangeable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, but I'm sure Word would have extra checks for such cases.

Comment: @Dog Lover I'm afraid you have a wrong view of the accuracy of grammar-checking programs. Look this up on ELU Meta to see the true situation.

Comment: So, are there exceptions to this? Another question, why is it okay to say "all my/your/his/her heart"? "Heart" is singular, right? Is this one of the exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

If lie is singular, then your computer is right, it's awkward to write "all the lie."  It would look to the reader like what you meant to say is "I'm sick of all the **lies**."

If you're trying to express that you're sick of *every part* of *one* lie, you have several options:

> I'm sick of **the whole** lie.
>
> I'm sick of **the entire** lie.

And you could use a thesaurus to find even more options.

If you want to say that you're sick of multiple lies, and you really want to keep "lie" singular for some reason, you could write:

> I'm sick of **every** lie.

Comment: Then why is "all of me" fine? "Me" is singular, right? Or is there a special rule for pronouns?

Comment: @Xyenz It's not a hard and fast rule. "All of" can be confusing when used with a singular definite noun, but one that cannot be pluralized isn't prone to such confusion. For instance you could say *she was the best in all of France* or *she was the best in the entire country*.